# Invoking a script as part of a web api method : how bad an idea is it?

Tags: powershell, security

I have a powershell script (but I think these considerations could be extended to any script that requires a runtime to interpret and execute it) that does what I also need to expose to a web application front end as a REST API to be called and I've been asked to call directly the script itself from the web method but although technically feasible, having a web api method that starts a shell/process to execute the script and redirecting stdin/stdout/stderr looks like a very bad practice to me. Is there any specific security risk in doing something like this?

Comment: Is the script/function a well-defined action, or do you take user input?

Comment: Good point, I'm receiving parameters to be used in calling the PowerShell script and will clearly validate them

Answer (score 1):

Reading this question brings to mind how many of the [OWASP Top Ten Security Vulnerabilities](https://owasp.org/www-project-top-ten/) it would expose your site to.

1. [Injection Flaws](https://owasp.org/www-project-top-ten/2017/A1_2017-Injection) - This is definitely a high risk. There are ways to remediate it, of course. Parameterizing all input with strongly-typed dates and numbers instead of strings is one method that can be used, but it may not fit with your business case. You should never allow user-provided code to be executed, but if you are accepting strings as input and running a script against that input, it becomes very difficult to prevent arbitrary code execution.
2. [Broken Authentication](https://owasp.org/www-project-top-ten/2017/A2_2017-Broken_Authentication) - possibly vulnerable. If you force a user to authenticate before reaching your script (you probably should), there is a chance that the user reuses their credentials elsewhere and exposes those credentials to a brute force attack. Do you lock out accounts after too many tries? Do you have two-factor authentication? Do you allow weak passwords? These are all considerations when you introduce a new authentication mechanism.
3. [Sensitive data exposure](https://owasp.org/www-project-top-ten/2017/A3_2017-Sensitive_Data_Exposure) - likely vulnerable, depending on your script. Does the script allow reading files and returning their contents? If not now, will it do so in the future? Even if it's never designed to do so, combined with other exploits the script might be able to read a file from a path that's outside the web directory. It's very difficult to prevent directory traversal exploits that would allow a malicious user access to your server, or even the entire network. Compiled code and the web server prevent this in many cases.
4. [XML External Entities](https://owasp.org/www-project-top-ten/2017/A4_2017-XML_External_Entities_(XXE)) - possibly vulnerable, depending on your requirements. If you allow user-provided XML, the bad guy can inject other files and create havoc. This is easier to trap when you're using standard web tools.
5. [Broken Access Control](https://owasp.org/www-project-top-ten/2017/A5_2017-Broken_Access_Control) - definitely vulnerable. A Web API application can enforce user controls, and set permission levels in a C# controller. Exceptions are handled with HTTP status codes that indicate the request was not allowed. In contrast, Powershell executes within the security context of the logged in user, and allows system-level changes even if not running escalated. If an injection flaw is exploited, the code would be executed in the web server's security context, not the user's. You may be surprised how much the IIS_USER (or other Application Pool service account) can do. For one, if the bad guy is executing in the context of a service account, they might be able to bring down your whole site with a single request by locking out that account or changing the password - a task that's much easier with a Powershell script than with compiled C# code.
6. [Security Misconfiguration](https://owasp.org/www-project-top-ten/2017/A6_2017-Security_Misconfiguration) - likely vulnerable. A running script would require it's own security configuration outside whatever framework you are using for the Web API. Are you ready to re-implement something like OAuth Claims or ACLs?
7. [Cross-Site Scripting](https://owasp.org/www-project-top-ten/2017/A7_2017-Cross-Site_Scripting_XSS) - likely vulnerable. Are you echoing the script output? If you're not sanitizing input and output, the script could echo some Javascript that sends a user's cookie content to a malicious server, giving them access to all the user's resources. [Cross site request forgery](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/csrf) is also a risk if input is not validated.
8. [Insecure Deserialization](https://owasp.org/www-project-top-ten/2017/A8_2017-Insecure_Deserialization) - Probably not vulnerable.
9. [Using Components with Known Vulnerabilities](https://owasp.org/www-project-top-ten/2017/A9_2017-Using_Components_with_Known_Vulnerabilities) - greatly increased vulnerability, compared to compiled. Powershell grants access to a whole set of libraries that would otherwise need explicit references in a compiled application.
10. [Insufficient Logging & Monitoring](https://owasp.org/www-project-top-ten/2017/A10_2017-Insufficient_Logging%2526Monitoring) - likely vulnerable. IIS logs requests by default, but Powershell doesn't log anything unless you explicitly write to a file or start a transcript. Neither method is designed for concurrency and may introduce performance or functional problems for shared files.

In short, 9 out of the top 10 Vulnerabilities may affect this implementation. I would hope that would be enough to prevent you making your script public, at the very least. Basically the problem is that you're using the tool (Powershell) for a purpose it wasn't intended to fulfill.

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed reply. Apart the poor performance of starting a powershell shell for each request, I also feel that the spawning of a new process each time is a risky situation in general that you would avoid if possible.